# I bought a bitcoin before my client sychronization was finished. Will I get the coin?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

I bought a bitcoin before my client synchronization was finished.

Will this stop me from getting the coin or will it just come later when the wallet is synchronized?

Comment: Err.. synchronization? Do you mean your client had not finished downloading the blockchain? That will not make a difference. If it had already generated a Bitcoin address, and you used that to have your one Bitcoin sent to, it will still have the associated wallet. In fact, you only need the wallet file to have access to your Bitcoin. But until your client sees the blocks with the transaction from which you got your bitcoin, it may not be able to display your new bitcoin balance correctly.

Answer (score 5):

No, it will not matter.  Sync only affects the readiness of your client.  The purchase is reflected on the public blockchain, which has nothing to do with whether your client is ready or not.

Comment: Oh that's a relief, so I will just have to wait then I guess? Thanks for you help Harold it's most appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you also for teh reply Pyramid, I have only just seen that answer. And yes it was not sychonized with network yet.

Comment: You can use a thin client like Multibit, and the synchronization is much faster because it doesn't download the whole blockchain.  But that doesn't mean that the *verification* of transactions will be faster.  Verifications are done on the public blockchain, and have nothing to do with your client.

Comment: What @HaroldNaparst said. But remember to keep your wallet file (or some other representation of the private key(s)) because you need that to get the coins in the wallet.