# Bitcoin Core Questions

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

I am new to Bitcoin core and I put in my private key. Then I saw "synchronizing" that was a day ago. Can not find where the bitcoins are. What should I do? My knowledge is limited with software.

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17092/i-bought-a-bitcoin-before-my-client-sychronization-was-finished-will-i-get-the

Answer (score 0):

You can either wait until the synchronization is finished (at which point there will be quite a decent amount of storage space used by Bitcoin Core) or you uninstall Bitcoin Core if you don't want to synchronize the entire blockchain and use an SPV client instead.

Have a look at [this table](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Clients#Table). It shows you how long it will take to get a certain wallet up and running and how much storage space it will need.